# php class file not found, even though it exists

Tags: php, class, websocket, phpwebsocket

So I'm trying to set up web sockets with php on a linux instance, and have two files. Both files are in my /var/www/html directory. The first one is called `Chat.php` and contains the following code:

```
<?php
namespace MyApp;
use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;

class Chat implements MessageComponentInterface {
    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
    }

    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
    }

    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
    }

    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {
    }
}

?>
```

The second is called `chat-server.php` and contains this code:

```
<?php
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use MyApp\Chat;

require dirname(__DIR__) . '/html/vendor/autoload.php';

$server = IoServer::factory(
    new Chat(),
    8084
);

$server->run();

?>
```

When I try to run `chat-server.php` I get the following error message:

`PHP Fatal error:  Class 'MyApp\Chat' not found in /var/www/html/chat-server.php on line 8`

So clearly, it does not like it when I try to initiate a `new Chat()` because it doesn't find the Class. Why not?

Comment: Because the class isn't in `chat-server.php`, it's in `Chat.php`. You would need to include `Chat.php` into `chat-server.php` so that it's aware of the class definition.

Comment: isn't that what `use MyApp\Chat;` is doing?

Comment: No, that's just making it so you can refer to the class as `Chat` instead of the absolute name of `MyApp\Chat` when you instantiate it. You'd still need something like `include "Chat.php";`.

Comment: That is, without `use MyApp\Chat`, you'd need to do `new MyApp\Chat()` instead of just `new Chat()`. But in either case, you still need to include/require it.

Comment: Ok did that, now when I run the file, it says PHP Fatal error:  `Interface 'Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface' not found in /var/www/html/Chat.php on line 6`

Comment: Makes sense.. I don't see anywhere in your code where you've defined `MessageComponentInterface`.

Comment: Isn't it included in the first file like this: `use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;`?

Comment: Again, that's not an include, that just allows you to reference it was `MessageComponentInterface` instead of having to use `Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface`. You still need to include the actual code, either by having the code for the class in the same file, or by using `include` or `require` to bring it in from an external file.

Comment: How come http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world doesn't have to `include` or `require`?

Comment: The autoloader is responsible for including all the required files, so you shouldn't have to do any manual include or require on the files. Moving the require autoloader line to be the first line in your code might help, if not you need to see what the autoloader do and check that you are structuring your code in the same way as the autoloader expects

Comment: The page you linked to is using Composer, which has an autoloader that includes all of the necessary dependency files. If you're not using this, then you need to include those files yourself.

Comment: rypskar, I moved the autoloader line to the top, that didn't help. How do I know if I'm structuring my code in the same way that the autoloader is?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to regenerate the Composer autoloader(autoload.php), after you first edit the composer.json file by adding something like the following under the autoload property:

```
"psr-4": {"MyApp\\": "/"}
```

This would define a new mapping between namespaces to directories.
Then, to regenerate the autoloading script , simply type:

```
composer dumpautoload -o
```

Also, requiring the autoloader should be placed top in your script.
For more details, check the official documentation of composer regarding autoloading: https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading